# Unrecognized argument type to convert to a FeatureCollection:

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, histogram

I am unable to chart a histogram for my region for each image in an image collection.

```
// Create clipping function
var clipper = function(image){
  return image.clip(geometry);
};


var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD09GQ').map(clipper);
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);

// Group by month, and then reduce within groups by mean();
// the result is an ImageCollection with one image for each
// month.

var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function(m) {
        return modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .filterBounds(geometry)  
                    .median()
                    .set('month', m);
}));

print("Monthly Images Median",byMonth);

//chart histogram of a single band
print(ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: byMonth.first().select(['sur_refl_b01']), 
  region: geometry.geometry().bounds,
  // maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01'}));
```

Error:

```
Unrecognized argument type to convert to a FeatureCollection: function standin(_0) {
    return newF.apply(this, arguments);
  }
```

Even though I am charting one month at a time, I would ideally like 12 histograms for 12 images in the collection, and a single chart with all 12 histograms drawn.

**EDIT** I tried the following and I get another error saying `unexpected argument type`

```
print(ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByRegion({
  image: byMonth,
  bandName: 'sur_refl_b01',
  regions: geometry,
  // reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'monthly median sur_refl_b01'}));
```

Error:

```
Unexpected arguments to function doySeriesByRegion(): image
```

Comment: @SeanRoulet Any thoughts?

Comment: I was able to generate a single image's histogram by changing the region argument in your ui.Chart function to `region: geometry,` (ie removing all that extra stuff). https://code.earthengine.google.com/acb79f18d9916e0b48616ecff8bee01d

Answer (score 1):

[this isn't a super elegant solution but it's a clunky starting point](https://code.earthengine.google.com/34b87770125f352976ed25a927ccb481).

I mapped the select function earlier on to the original image collection, then made a histogram for each layer in `byMonth`. These are then all plotted simultaneously which doesn't give you a single figure but at least prints everything out at once...

```
var maineCounties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Waldo'));
print(maineCounties);
var geometry = maineCounties;

// Create clipping function
var clipper = function(image){
  return image.clip(geometry);
};


var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD09GQ').map(clipper)                    .map(function(image){return(image.select("sur_refl_b01"))});
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);

// Group by month, and then reduce within groups by mean();
// the result is an ImageCollection with one image for each
// month.

var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function(m) {
        return modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .filterBounds(geometry)  
                    .median()
                    .set('month', m);
}));

print("Monthly Images Median",byMonth);
print("First month",byMonth.first());

var listOfImages = byMonth.toList(byMonth.size());
var img1 = listOfImages.get(0);
var img2 = listOfImages.get(1);
var img3 = listOfImages.get(2);
var img4 = listOfImages.get(3);
var img5 = listOfImages.get(4);
var img6 = listOfImages.get(5);
var img7 = listOfImages.get(6);
var img8 = listOfImages.get(7);
var img9 = listOfImages.get(8);
var img10 = listOfImages.get(9);
var img11 = listOfImages.get(10);
var img12 = listOfImages.get(11);
print("Computed image 2",img2);

//chart histogram of a single band
var C1 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img1, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Jan'});
var C2 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img2, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Feb'});
var C3 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img3, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Mar'});
var C4 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img4, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Apr'});
var C5 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img5, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, May'});
var C6 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img6, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Jun'});
var C7 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img7, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Jul'});
var C8 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img8, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Aug'});
var C9 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img9, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Sep'});
var C10 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img10, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Oct'});
var C11 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img11, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Nov'});
var C12 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img12, 
  region: geometry,
  maxBuckets: 10,
  scale: 250
}).setOptions({title: 'modis median band 01, Dec'});

print("All histograms",C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,C11,C12);
```

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting although it defeats the purpose of not using .map() ? Would be ideal to write a function that loops through the same as opposed to using .listOfImages() multiple times?

Comment: @VijayRamesh - Ideally yeah it would be awesome to loop through with `.map()` but I was thinking it wasn't possible to map functions like `print()` and `addLayer()`. Hoping to see better solutions to come...

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for your solution. Will wait to see if there are better solutions as well. It does the job for now :)

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe Since you have written a bunch of functions for the same, I thought I would tag you here.

Comment: I tried a different function, but I am getting another error now.